# How to use CSS3 Transform.translate to set the elements real position?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 input buttons

I want to move btn1 below btn2 on mouse hover/button click. I referred http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html to get the position of btn2 and gave the x and y accordingly to the Transform: translate method. But btn1 moves to different location on the page. The coordinates given to translate method are not working as expected.
Need help to determine the correct coordinates to transform.

Comment: What co-ordinates are you giving to the translate method?  It would help you to get useful answers if you added your current code to the question or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of `translate` are relative to the original position of the element. If you want those to represent an absolute position on the page set the element to `0,0` first:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Probably a better way to do it (without absolute positioning) would be to get the position of both of the elements, calculate the difference and pass it to `translate`.